# Error with plotly() in R with large dataset

Tags: r, plotly

I am trying to plot a large data file. It is 1.5 GB in size. I am running R on a computer with pretty big memory (192 GB RAM). It is just x vs y as the following code

```
df <- data.frame(time = seq(10^8), x = rnorm(10^8))
fig <- plot_ly(data = df, x = ~time, y = ~x, type = "scatter", mode = "lines")
fig
```

After about 5 minutes, I am getting this error:

```
Error in collapse_object(objnames, tmp, indent) : 
  R character strings are limited to 2^31-1 bytes
```

Is this a limitation with R or plotly? There is enough RAM, so I don't think that is the issue here. Is there another way to make an interactive plot with large dataframes?

Comment: Practically speaking, how will you select individual points if you have 100M to display? Plotly might be ok with 1M (https://plotly.com/r/webgl-vs-svg-million-points/) but it's not made for much larger data. You might try dygraphs? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56824930/interactive-plotting-of-large-data-few-millions-with-r

Comment: [testing this out, dygraphs probably not up to it, getting pretty sluggish for me with 5M point.]

Comment: @JonSpring - I can confirm that `dygraph()` returned the same error as `plot_ly()` for a df with 100M rows.

Comment: If you're willing to consider non-R solutions, Streamlit (Python) is pretty good with big data: see for example https://vaex.io/blog/vaex-plus-streamlit-where-simplicity-meets-big-data.